# Creating a Postgresql Database with CakePHP 3

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp-3.0

In the documentation it says,

> If you want to create a connection without selecting a database you
>   can omit the database name:
>
> $dsn = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/'; You can now use your
>   connection object to execute queries that create/modify databases. For
>   example to create a database:
>
> $connection->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_database");
>
> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#creating-databases

However this of course doesn't work for postgresql.  Does anyone have an example of how you might do the same thing but with postgresql?

I've tried various methods but almost all of them give me this error.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: database "user='MyPGUsername'" does not exist
```

NOTE : this error comes even if I create the database `MyPGUsername`.

Comment: Your DSN tells cakePHP to use a MySQL database. If you have one running on your localhost then it connects to it.

Comment: that dsn is from the cakephp documentation, not from my code.  I've tried a million different dsn's they all give me the error I described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this might help anyone else, I solved this by just doing php instead of any CakePHP method.

```
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' . $dbName . ' WITH TEMPLATE=' . $config['dbtemplate'] . ' ENCODING=UTF8';
$query = pg_query($connection, $sql);
pg_close($connection);
if($query){
    return true;
} else {
    throw new Exception(pg_last_error($connection));
}
```